# how to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react-highlight-words

Tags: reactjs

I want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react-highlight-words package in Highlighter tag.

```
          <Highlighter
            activeClassName=""
            activeIndex=...
            highlightClassName=...
            highlightStyle=...
            searchWords={srchArr}
            autoEscape=...
            textToHighlight={{ __html: string}}
          />
```

textToHighlight is giving me [Object Object] in result.
How i solve it?
Please help!

Comment: I've got the similar problem, could you please post the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `[Object Object]` because of this line,

```
 textToHighlight={{ __html: string}}
```

Here `string` might be an `Object`, you should use this,

```
 textToHighlight={{ __html: JSON.stringify(string)}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got solution :)

Comment: I know its been awhile, but I tried your solution, but getting following error:
```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `textToHighlight` of type `object` supplied to `Highlighter`, expected `string`.
```|

and I'm using `textToHighlight={{ __html: JSON.stringify(string)}}`